# Commutative and Orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ and the identity I, show that the matrices (I+M) AND $(I-M)^{-1}$ commute.

For a real skew- symmetric matrix A, the matrix N is defined by

$N=(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}$

Prove that N is orthogonal

For the 1st part,We have to show that $(I+M)(I-M)^{-1}=(I-M)^{-1}$

Let $B=(I+M)(I-M)^{-1}$

Pre-multiply by (I-M):

$(I-M)B=(I-M)(I+M)(I-M)^{-1}$

$(I-M)B=(I^2-M^2)(I-M)^{-1}$

$(I-M)B=(I+M)(I-M)(I-M)^{-1}$

$(I-M)B=(I+M)$

Premultiply  by $(I-M)^{-1}$

$B=(I-M)^{-1}(I+M)$

For the 2nd part,  $A$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, hence $A^{T}=-A$

$N=(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}$, required to prove that $N$ is orthogonal.

$NN^{T}=I$

$NN^{T}=[(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}][(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}]^T$

=$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}[(I-A)^{-1}]^{T}(I+A)^T$

=$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}[(I-A)^T]^{-1}(I+A)^T$

=$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}[(I^T-A^T)^{-1}(I^T+A^T)]$

We use property of A shown above, $A^{T}=-A$

=$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)^{-1}(1-A)$

By the commutative property, we obtain $NN^T=I$

Comment: What have you tried to do? Your question looks like you copied it straight out of a problem list, and that is usually a **really bad** idea... Please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), specially the part about showing your work.

Comment: The number of questions in this post looks a lot like "$2$" to me.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I usually show my working when I reach the result.

Comment: Well, The question got closed for precisely that reason.